# MySQL performing math operations on strings?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby

I am trying to store latitude and longitude information in MySQL.  I am using Ruby to parse the latitude and longitude data. They are parsed separately and then combined into a string variable. So if I have:

```
latitude = 43.78219.to_s
longitude = -75.00326.to_s
location = latitude + " " + longitude  # => "43.78219 -75.00326"
```

I have a table in MySQL to store this data, and the data type is set to String varchar.  The problem is that when I insert the location string into the table, MySQL performs a math operation and subtracts the two numbers in the string. Then I'm like Whaaaaaaaaa???????
So it ends up storing -31.22107 as the location.  Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the query I'm using

```
db.query("insert into StationCapacityStatus
        (city_id, station_id, location, empty_docks, nonempty_docks, timestamp) 
        values(
            23,
            #{$station_number},
            #{location},
            #{$empty_docks},
            #{$nonempty_docks},
            #{$datetime}
        )"
)
```

Comment: Add the query you are using to save it to the database.  Chances are if it isn't in quotes, then it is picking it up as an equation.

Comment: I'd store them in seperate columns anyways.

Comment: @judda Just added the query I was using.

Comment: I agree with peterbond here.  It makes more logical sense to split them up.  I don't know ruby enough to know the syntax on how to change your query, so I'll leave that to someone else.

Comment: I guess I'll have to go the 2 columns route to reduce the headache.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not quoting the `location` so MySQL's sees a plain `43.78219 -75.00326` inside the VALUES and interprets it as a floating point expression. You should use [`quote`](http://rubydoc.info/github/luislavena/mysql-gem/master/Mysql#quote-instance_method) method to properly escape the strings as well:

```
db.query("insert into StationCapacityStatus
    (city_id, station_id, location, empty_docks, nonempty_docks, timestamp) 
    values(
        23,
        #{$station_number},
        '#{db.quote(location)}',
        #{$empty_docks},
        #{$nonempty_docks},
        #{$datetime}
    )"
)
```

You should also switch to prepared statements with bound values if possible:

```
sth = db.prepare('insert into StationCapacityStatus (city_id, station_id, location, empty_docks, nonempty_docks, timestamp) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')
sth.execute(23, $station_number, location, $empty_docks, $nonempty_docks, $datetime)
```

Comment: @icanc: You're welcome, separate columns (and `db.prepare`) is a good plan.